# Use #define preprocessor directive in a weird way

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, identifier

Today I just finish reading and experimenting on **C** about how to use `#define` to create a manifest constant, after that something came into my mind, and below is the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define dummy main
#define yam {
#define apple }

int dummy(void)        //constant substitution main with dummy
yam                          // constant substitution { with yam
  printf("It works!!\n");
  return 0;
apple                           //constant substitution } with apple
```

As expected, it works like charm, I just wonder why something like that didn't cause any error, maybe I could understand why the `main()` could be substituted because `main` is an identifier (name given to a function, variable and constant), but why the `{}` can be substituted with a symbolic name too? The second thing is, what data type **C** use to store this symbolic constant which is not a character enclosed in single quote `""` nor an integer or floating-point number.

Comment: For the love of all that's holy, don't abuse the preprocessor in such awful ways!

Comment: haha @Philip , i just feel curious about it so i did this,i don't think i'm not going to code any software with this kind of method

Comment: So , in what datatype does the text { and } stored??because i didn't enclosed it in single quotation

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `#define` statements are evaluated by a preprocessor **before the program is actually compiled**, so the compiler never sees `yam`. The preprocessor performs a direct text substitution.

That is to say, when the compiler sees your code, it looks like this:

```
int main(void)        //constant substitution main with dummy
{                          // constant substitution { with yam
  printf("It works!!\n");
  return 0;
}                           //constant substitution } with apple
```

Answer (score 2):

Define is literally text replacement. In the preprocessor steps, the compiler will go through your code and replace all `dummy` with `main`, `yam` with `{`, and `apple` with `}`.

Answer (score 2):

This works because the preprocessor is a **PRE**processor, i.e. it's something that happens before the real processing.

So the preprocessor does its crude text substitution stuff before the real compiler gets to look at the code.

Answer (score 2):

`#define` is handled by the preprocessor. The stuff will be replaced character by character before the compiler compiles the code. You're essentially able to obscure your whole code using `#define` but anyone with a precompiler can unobscure it later on. The preprocessor replaces all occurances of the "constant" you defined, except when it's enclosed in quotes (e.g. `char *test="dumy yam apple";` will stay unchanged).